# What happens to the cache on page fault?

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, processor

In a processor, what happens to the cache when the operating system replaces a page, if there is not enough space to hold all running processes' pages in memory? Does it need to flush the cache on every page replacement?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a page is swapped in, the contents are read off the disk and into memory. Typically this is done using DMA. So the real question is, "How is the cache kept coherent with DMA?". You can either have DMA talk to the cache controller on each access, or make the OS manage the cache manually. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access#Cache_coherency.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what happens in details, but caches and virtual memory using paging
are similar: both are divided in "pages".

The same way that only one page needs to be replaced in a page fault, only one line of
the cache needs to be replaced when it occurs a miss on the cache. The cache has 
several "pages" (lines), but only the problematic page will be replaced.

There are other things that I do not know if takes part on such replacements: cache size,
cache coherency - write-through/back and so on. I hope someone else can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: If there are not enough pages in memory, there is a risk of error.

Comment: Consider a memory with only two pages. (The operating system occupies the first one.) Assuming that each process fills one page, the OS must replace the second physical page on each context switch. Cache entries corresponding to the second physical page are invalid.

Comment: In the case of a context switch, yes. But I do not know for certain what happens in a situation where there is a page fault within the process.